# How to investigate memory leak further

Tags: java, memory-leaks

My app has constantly growing CMS Old Gen. I took dumps from several instances of the app and opened it with eclipse MAT. It shows 1 leak suspect:

```
8,260 instances of "java.lang.Class", loaded by "<system class loader>" occupy 6,371,584 (22.08%) bytes.

Biggest instances:

class java.lang.invoke.MethodType @ 0xd4e40f50 - 585,512 (2.03%) bytes.
class sun.security.jca.Providers @ 0xd55c4648 - 537,272 (1.86%) bytes.[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

If i search for object 0xd4e40f50 I see a big hashmap with lots of method references. looks like all methods used in the app

[image]

the other address 0xd55c4648 gives list of security providers.
[image]

This is used by java process and is not specific to my application. Can anyone suggest how to investigate the leak further? can this mean that there is a circular dependency somewhere? what else can be the cause of the leak with such symptoms?

Comment: What leads you to conclude that there's a memory leak as opposed to just normal memory usage? What you posted above is that 8,260 objects are using 6,371,584 bytes, which is ~6MB. That by itself looks completely normal.